# Consuming Soap based XML Service

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0, soap

I'm trying to pass XML over SOAP based service. Here I'm creating my xml directly from my stored procedure and accessing the returned xml.
the code to fetch the XML given below:

```
public XmlDataDocument GetData()
{
    string msg = string.Empty;

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ToString());

    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "usp_YoOne_Request";
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandTimeout = 600;

        XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();

        XmlDataDocument xml = new XmlDataDocument();
        xml.Load(reader);
        connection.Close();

        return xml;
    }

}
```

This works great and is reading the XML and return the xml. But when I try to consume this service in my test application its not working. The code I'm using to consume the xml.

**Updated:** As you can see all the other ways I tried did not work for me. about endpoints, it does call the GetData() method from the service and return xmldocument with no error. during debug it does show the xml is correct. the only issues lies on consuming the returned xml.

```
        class Class1
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                BankOperatorsYoClient proxy = new BankOperatorsYoClient();

                XmlDataDocument addResult = proxy.GetData(); // Doest not allow me to call my function here 
               // error: Cannot implicitly convert object[] to System.Xml.XmlDataDocument

               var addResult = proxy.GetData(); //Does not work and gives error
              //Additional information: An error occurred while receiving
// the HTTP response to http://localhost:57881/BankoService.svc. This could be 
//due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could 
//also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly
 //due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

             object[] addResult = proxy.PutData(); // Gives the same error as above

                Console.WriteLine("Result of Add Operation");

                Console.WriteLine(addResult);

                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

        }
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. If any one can help me with this or can tell me what am i doing wrong. I searched for solution on google but unable to identify the issue with this code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Doest not allow me to call my function here"? What is the error message?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin : please check my edited question for  error: Cannot implicitly convert 'object[]' to 'System.Xml.XmlDataDocument'

Comment: The GetData method of your proxy is returning an object array. To investigate can you replace the line with `var addResult = proxy.GetData();` and look at the addResult variable?

Comment: when I use "var" it gives this error {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}                                       Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:57881/BankoService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. Let me update my question.

Comment: Why are you using `XmlDataDocument`? It is obsolete and unsupported. Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Also, did you "see the server logs"? What did they say?

Comment: @JohnSaunders : I have tried replacing it with XmlDocument. still same problem

Comment: That would be due to the fact the service is returning `object[]`.

Comment: but how could that be? as I am returning xml from my service function.

Comment: What is your data volume? If you have a lot of data returned you could try to set/increase the `MaxRequestLength` attribute

Comment: although the issue isn't about the data volume, but FYI I'm try with very small data volume